# try/catch block not working in actionlistener

Tags: java, user-interface, try-catch, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am working on 2 programs for school, one to take contact info and save it to a text file and the other is to read from the text file. All works perfectly but I have to add a try/catch block the program that takes input so that it would catch non-numeric entries in the age text field. I have been trying many different ways of doing this since yesterday and nothing has been working. Below is the code. If someone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful because I feel like there is something fundamental I am not getting here. Thanks

```
  private class SaveData implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            String age1 = (String)ageField.getText();
            int age = Integer.parseInt(age1);

            try{
                int a = age;
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter an     Integer");
            }

            String name = (String)nameField.getText();
            String email = (String)emailField.getText();
            String cell = (String)cellField.getText();  

            if(age>= 0 && age<=120){
                outputFile.println("Name: " + name);
                outputFile.println("Age: " + age);
                outputFile.println("Email: " + email);
                outputFile.println("Cell #: " +cell);
                outputFile.println("---------------------------");

                nameField.setText("");
                ageField.setText("");
                emailField.setText("");
                cellField.setText("");
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered an invalid age \n " +
                                        "Please enter an age between 0 and 120",
                                                "Age Entry Error",      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                nameField.setText("");
                ageField.setText("");
                emailField.setText("");
                cellField.setText("");
            }//end else
        }//end actionperformed
    }//end actionlistener
```

Comment: `int a = age;` will never throw an exception. Move `Integer.parseInt` inside the `try`

Comment: If you have found an answer, you should post it here and mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So essentially I see three problems(including the ones that you aren't having problems with- yet):

- The function `parseInt` throws an exception but you are not catching it because it is not in the `try` block.
- You are catching the wrong exception so it will never be caught. You can read the Javadoc for that exception [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).
- The variable `age` is unreachable outside of the `try`/`catch` block due to scoping rules.

Here is how you should do it:

`String age1 = (String)ageField.getText();
    int age = -1;//always assign a variable a default value
    try{
        age = Integer.parseInt(age1);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException err){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid Integer!");
    }`

Final thought, if you are catching an exception, then you should display an error (which you are doing) and then return from that function. So essentially there should be a return in that `catch` block, as you don't want to continue to execute further code. Which will most likely fail because it expects a valid `age` value.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have made the recommended changes and all works perfectly. Awesome profile pic by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Simply write down `int age = Integer.parseInt(age1);` these lines inside try/catch block and catch for `NumberFormatException` Exception.

Comment: I had tried that but then the age variable will not be recognized outside the try-catch block. All the other code that writes the data to the file will not work. Is there a work around this?

Comment: int age=0;

            try{
age = Integer.parseInt(age1);
            }

Here declared variable outside the try block but initialize inside block